# How to "zf create project .." using a different profile? REST/console/etc

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-tool

I want to write yet another REST service, but this time using ZF tool. I wonder if there are already suitable project profiles for that around?

After creating a project with a default profile **zf tool** says

```
Note: This command created a web project, for more information setting up your VHOST, please see docs/README
```

Obvious to assume there exists a profile mechanism and hopefully other profiles.

Let me know if you came across those non-vanilla profiles (REST, console, etc.). [Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/learning.quickstart.create-project.html) per say seems to be a bit silent on custom profiling. **Note:** Alternatively a tutorial on developing your own custom profile is welcomed.

PS In case of REST it is obvious enough that one can reuse vanilla web profile following steps similar to this [tutorial](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/). But it would be much nicer to have a profile that takes into consideration better practice of using REST router as in [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.rest) (hence a proper non-RPC approach).

**[EDIT]**

- first part of the question - working with project profiles of
  zf-tool is a duplicate of
  [zf create project path name-of-profile file-of-profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237765/zf-create-project-path-name-of-profile-file-of-profile)
- second part of the question is to find/create such profile for 
  REST (based on ZF)

Answer (score 0):

code & tutorial: https://github.com/codeinchaos/restful-zend-framework

Comment: Looks good. I have found another REST ZF tutorial http://www.techchorus.net/create-restful-applications-using-zend-framework that is also quite nice. So how about creating a project profile for zend tool?

Comment: that other tutorial doesn't cover input/output data conversion (JSON/XML/etc ...) but its a good start!

Comment: as for zend tool, there is a very similar way, basically using routing to do CLI routing, which I believe is built in as well ...

Comment: I am not sure you are a following about *zf tool*. To run 'zf project create rest' will require writing a class for REST project layout that will provide project information (profile). See http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Tool/Project/Provider/Project.php